# Как вынести содержимое select в поле input?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, mysqli

Как вынести содержимое select в поле input?

---

```
<form method="post" action='save_word.php'>
<select id="kek" name="bla" onchange="document.getElementById('suda').text+=text+','" style="width:100%;">
<option> вот этот текст засунуть в инпут suda </option>
</select>             
<span style="display:none" class="total">0</span>
<input style="display:none" type="hidden" name="total" class="total_input" value="" />
<input type='text' class="suda" name="suda" id='suda' />
</form >
```

Comment: укажите более конкретнее что вы хотите получить

Comment: Мне нужно вывести данные с формы в вордовский документ. У меня это получается только с полем input. Так вот есть: <select> <option> блаблабла </option> </select> и есть <input type=text> Мне нужно блаблабла засунуть в input при выборе блаблабла

Comment: покажите ваш код

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.sample').on('change', function() {
            var value = $('#suda').val();

            value = (value === '') ? value = this.value : value + ', '+this.value;

            $('#suda').val(value);
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="post" action='save_word.php'>
    <select class="sample" name="op1" style="width:100%;">
        <option> Выберете значение </option>
        <option> текст 1</option>
        <option> текст 2</option>
        <option> текст 3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="sample" name="op2" style="width:100%;">
        <option> Выберете значение </option>
        <option> текст 1</option>
        <option> текст 2</option>
        <option> текст 3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="sample" name="op3" style="width:100%;">
        <option> Выберете значение </option>
        <option> текст 1</option>
        <option> текст 2</option>
        <option> текст 3</option>
    </select>
    <span style="display:none" class="total">0</span>
    <input style="display:none" type="hidden" name="total" class="total_input" value="" />
    <input type='text' class="suda" name="suda" id='suda' />
</form >
```

Comment: если результат вас устраивает, отметьте ответ как "Принятый"

Comment: можете пожалуйста по name или по классу?

Comment: у меня тоже получилось, но только по id: $('#kek').on('change',function(){
$('#suda').val(this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent+=this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent);
});

Comment: не очень понимаю что вы имеете в виду

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы по name или по классу обращался, а не по id, потому что данных много. А еще мне нужно, чтобы данные суммировались в текстовом поле, потому что селектов много :) Чтобы каждый выбор, который я делаю, заносился в текстовое поле input через запятую

Comment: по тэгу name получилось сделать, но теперь не знаю как сделать так, чтобы он каждый раз прибавлял строку в поле input. Например выбираю в <option> блабла </option> в input заносится блабла, потом другой select выбираю и выбираю <option> кек </option>. В input заносится "блабла, кек" через запятую и так далее

Comment: поправил свой ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое. Извини, а можешь сделать так, чтобы не при изменении select, а при выбранном select, то есть если if($(this).is(':selected')) тогда строка с содержимым добавляется в инпут. Если даже будем нажимать на другие option's, то строчка не добавляет, а вот если другой select, то строчка добавляется и мы запоминаем последний выбранный option на предыдущем select. Такое реально сделать? :) Извини, если надоел

Comment: реально, но у меня уже нет времени